# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable running exe made with pyinstaller

Tags: python, windows, opengl, pyinstaller

When trying to run an exe I made using pyinstaller it fails while importing OpenGL with this traceback:

```
(env) C:\Users\me\myProject>.\dist\myProject\myProject.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    from igtools import IG
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "OpenGL\GL\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "OpenGL\error.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 476, in exec_module
  File "OpenGL\platform\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
  File "OpenGL\platform\__init__.py", line 30, in _load
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
[38272] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm not sure exactly what the issue was. It seems like it had something to do with the pyinstaller hooks which I don't fully understand, but I did get it working with this specific combination of release versions:

```
pyinstaller==4.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib==2020.9
PyOpenGL==3.1.5
```

Maybe this will be helpful if anyone else runs into this.

Comment: Your PyInstaller version is too old, please upgrade to the recent ones (4.7).

Comment: 4.7 is the version I was originally using iirc. Maybe I should try to reproduce this err with less code and submit issue to pyinstaller.